# Basic linear algebra doubt

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have read the following equality, but I am unable to understand the steps leading from one to the other. The equations are
$$ 
\begin{align}
c &= A^+(I_N-B)^{-1}Ab + (I_L-A^+A)b, \\
c &= b + A^+B(I_N-B)^{-1}Ab,
\end{align}
$$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times L}$, $A^+\in\mathbb{R}^{L\times N}$ (indeed, $A^+$ is the pseudoinverse of $A$), $B\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, $c\in\mathbb{R}^{L}$, $b\in\mathbb{R}^{L}$ and $I_M$ stands for the identity matrix of dimension $M\times M$.

Additionally I know some extra properties (some of them may be too obvious or irrelevant). Let $M_1 = A^+A$ and $M_2 = I_L - A^+A$ we have that $M^2_1= M_1$, $M^2_2= M_2$, $M_1M_2=M_2M_1=0$, $M_1+M_2= I_L$, $AM_1=M_1A^+=A$, $AM_2=M_2A^+=0$, $M_2=I_L-M_1$. I guess that I may need some these properties... but not sure. For now I only could do the following

$$
\begin{align}
c &= A^+(I_N-B)^{-1}Ab + (I_L-A^+A)b, \\
c &= [A^+(I_N-B)^{-1}A + (I_L-A^+A)]b,\\
c &= A^+(I_N)^{-1}Ab + b - A^+Ab, \\
c &= b + [A^+(I_N-B)^{-1} - A^+]Ab, \\
c &= b + A^+[(I_N - B)^{-1} - I_N]Ab.
\end{align}
$$

I guess there is a missing (basic, and obvious) property that I don't know that allows to go from $A^+[(I_N - B)^{-1} - I_N]Ab$ to $A^+B(I_N-B)^{-1}Ab$.

I would appreciate any clue. Thanks in advance,

Comment: How can $c$ be a real number and $b \in \mathbf{R}^L$? Is $L = 1$?

Comment: Sorry it was a msitake, $c\in\mathbb{R}^L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensions that you wrote don't fit for multiplications. I suppose it should be $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times L}, A^{+} \in \mathbb{R}^{L \times N}$.

Next, your derivations lead to the solution. You can show that:

$$
(I_N - B)^{-1}-I_N = B(I_N-B)^{-1} \quad (*)
$$

by simply checking that:

$$
(I_N - B)^{-1} = I_N + B(I_N-B)^{-1} \quad (1)
$$

which is true, because:

$$
(I_N + B(I_N-B)^{-1})(I_N-B) = I_N-B+B = I_N
$$

(and hence the matrix on the right in (1) is a left inverse for the matrix on the left in (1), and therefore it is an inverse matrix)

Now you can use $(*)$ to go between things you wanted to go between, and it conludes the solution.

Note that pseudoinversity is not needed in the solution.